# HTTP Request Ignoring Body

Tags: apex, trigger, httpresponse

I have written a trigger that parses url's stored in a number of objects and requests them to see if they are still valid.

```
private Boolean pollserver(string url, string referer)
    {
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 

      req.setEndpoint(url);
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setHeader('Referer', referer);

      HTTPResponse res;
      Http http = new Http();
      if(!test.isRunningTest())
      {
        res = http.send(req);   
      }
      else
      {
        //We're running as a test, lets set some mock data
        res = new HTTPresponse();
        if(url == this.ValidURL)
        {
            res.setStatusCode(200);
        }
        else
        {
            res.setStatusCode(404);
        }
      }


      system.debug(url);
      System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
      System.debug('');

      return isFound(res);            
    }
```

It works fine, except when the file being returned is larger than 3mb.  Is there a good way to implement a 'ping' in Apex so I can see if a request completed without actually requesting the body?  Thanks!

Comment: use a HEAD request rather than GET, that'll return all the headers for the URL, but not the actual body.

Comment: I can not believe that didn't occur to me already...  Thanks!

Comment: @super post that as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a HEAD request rather than a GET, the server will return all the headers associated with the URL (and so you can tell if it exists, content type etc), but won't return the body.

so instead of `req.setMethod('GET');` you'd do `req.setMethod('HEAD');`

Comment: Might be worth just adding code to demonstrate where you set that. :)